# How can I plot an onmousedown event as value of what is stored at a certain index of an array, and not the entire array call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

Sorry if the question title is a little confusing, but I'm not sure exactly how to word my problem.

I have the following synchronous ajax call (the purpose of which is to get json file contents).

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/JsonControl/Events.json",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(jsonObj) 
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.events.length; ++i) 
        {
            if(day == jsonObj.events[i].dateNumber && (navDate.getMonth() + monthAdjust) == (jsonObj.events[i].dateMonth -1) && navDate.getFullYear() == jsonObj.events[i].dateYear)
            {
                document.getElementById("cGrid" + gridMod).className="eventDay";
                document.getElementById("cGrid" + gridMod).onmousedown = function(){document.getElementById("eventBox").src="/Event htms/Event.htm"; document.getElementById("eventBox").document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = (jsonObj.events[i].title);}
                document.getElementById("cGrid" + gridMod).style.backgroundColor = "#336633";
                isAnEvent = true;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The problem I am having is with the following line (line 12, if '$.ajax({' is line 1):

```
document.getElementById("cGrid" + gridMod).onmousedown = function(){document.getElementById("eventBox").src="/Event htms/Event.htm"; document.getElementById("eventBox").document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = (jsonObj.events[i].title);}
```

I have been told that I need closure, but I can't make heads or tails of any examples I have seen, as I have never seen syntax set up in such a way, and examples I have tried don't work (I will give details on what "don't work" means further down).

This is what I attempted (I replaced the concerning line mentioned above with this one, shown below).

```
(function(index) {
                document.getElementById("cGrid" + gridMod).onmousedown = function(){document.getElementById("eventBox").src="/Event htms/Event.htm"; document.getElementById("eventBox").document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = jsonObj.events[index].title;}
            })(i);
```

The error I get is this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementById' of undefined
```

I get this error with the original problem line, as well as, with the replacement line, just shown above.

I find this self-executing function stuff pretty new, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Any advice on how to plot what the actual value of jsonObj.events[i].title at the time it is accessed instead of literally plotting 'jsonObj.events[i].title' would be greatly appreciated.

I also tried (guessing, as I was) the valueOf method, but quick research has shown that simply returns the value of a boolean value.

Comment: The error is coming from `document.getElementById("eventBox").document.getElementById("title").innerHTML`

Comment: Based on my research that is what I should use to access an element within an iframe from the parent page. Is that wrong?

Comment: An `<iframe>`'s document should be accessed with `.contentDocument` (or `.contentWindow.document`) assuming you're passing the same origin policy.

Comment: @PaulS. I guess that's beyond me, too. It just produces a slew of errors when I use that instead of document. I'll have to read up on it before I'll understand it, I'm sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combination of wrapping the in-loop code ([as suggested by Justin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14205273/1615483)) with moving to [`.contentDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/iframe#Scripting) for `<iframe>` contents, along with a couple other changes.

See comments in code or ask below to understand what is happening. (I'm assuming *#eventBox* is an `<iframe>`)

```
function (jsonObj) {
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.events.length; ++i) (function (i) { // `i` inside function is protected from outside changes
        var cGridMod; // holder to reduce lookups
        if (day == jsonObj.events[i].dateNumber
          && (navDate.getMonth() + monthAdjust) == (jsonObj.events[i].dateMonth -1)
          && navDate.getFullYear() == jsonObj.events[i].dateYear) {
            cGridMod = document.getElementById("cGrid" + gridMod);
            cGridMod.className="eventDay";
            cGridMod.onmousedown = function () {
                var eventBox = document.getElementById("eventBox"); // holder to reduce lookups
                eventBox.onload = function () { // set an onload listener so #document exists at time of execution
                    eventBox.onload = null; // unset it so it only fires once
                    eventBox.contentDocument.getElementById("title").innerHTML = (jsonObj.events[i].title);
                      // using `.contentDocument` to get <iframe> document
                };
                eventBox.src="/Event htms/Event.htm";
                  // now set location (done after so onload will fire when loaded)
            };
            cGridMod.style.backgroundColor = "#336633";
            isAnEvent = true;
        }
    }(i)); // invoke the function for this iteration of the loop; `i`
}
```

Comment: I have read through your code here, and I must say, I don't 'think' there is anything I really don't understand. I have never used contentDocument before, but I'm assuming based off of previous feedback, that I should always use that, instead of document, when accessing an iframe's elements from the parent document. I am also assuming that your code, in its entirety should be placed as the success function from my '$.ajax' function. Is that right?

Comment: After trying this code (in the place I stated above) I have to say it was a huge success. Now that I know it works, I will spend time going through it again, line for line, and make sure I understand the differences in why this is working and not my original code. I do understand the circumstances surrounding the main issue, though, that is, the necessity for the self-executing function and protection of the 'i' variable from outside changes. THANK YOU SO MUCH for all of your help. I know I couldn't have worked through this one without your help.

Comment: One part of the syntax I don't understand is this here:    "for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.events.length; ++i) (function (i) {"    I mean I understand what it's there for, but, to me, it seems that the "(function (i)" part exists in the limbo between the for loop call and its first opening curly brace. This might be a tell-tale sign of a newbie here, but in all the (limited) code I've seen, I've never seen anything placed here syntactically.  Is there anywhere I can go to read up on what is allowed to be placed here and what, exactly, that means?

Comment: @VoidKing "it seems that the "(function (i)" part exists in the limbo between the for loop call and its first opening curly brace", Okay, time to have everything you know about _JavaScript_ blown out of the water. **You can omit curly braces.** In this case, the engine assumes a code block until the next delimiter `;` (or where it would be inserted because `;` can be omitted, too, _but I personally don't like doing that_ ). If you're not comfortable with this you can simply add them back in.

Comment: ..I thought I'd better point out that you can't actually omit `{` and `}` everywhere; they are needed for object literals and only Gecko supports omitting them in function definitions. You can omit them for most other things though, e.g. `if`, `else`, `while`, `for`, `do`, `with`.

Comment: Wow! that's interesting. That's yet another thing I have learned from you. I don't mind them being omitted, as long as I understand what's going on. So, it is the for loop that has both of its curly braces removed?

Comment: One thing I wouldn't expect to work about the code, and this really kind of baffles me, is the fact that it changes the innerHTML (accessing them by id, even) of the iframe elements before the iframe src is changed to the appropriate page. With my somewhat limited understanding of JavaScript, I thought that the elements would have to be loaded before it would even know what ids are available, let alone actually change their html content. The path to the file itself is never even given to JavaScript until after it accesses and changes these elements.

Comment: ^^Oops, I see, it changes the src after the onload function, which is a listener, and doesn't get executed until after the page loads. Durp.

Comment: It may be worth any future readers of this answer to note that any IE browser before 8 won't recognize the contentDocument call. To make this solution more cross-browser friendly, just before using contentDocument you could use this to reassign eventBox: **eventBox = eventBox.contentDocument || eventBox.contentWindow.document** and then take the contentDocument out of the innerHTML call. That is how I have ended up writing mine, and it works on current browsers, although this I have no machine running IE 7 or under, but the contentWindow.document is a known way that IE used to access iframes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because the mousedown event is always going to use the very last index in the for loop, you need to wrap the for loop using a function to make sure it's value is maintained properly.

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.events.length; ++i) (function(i){
 ....stuff here

})(i)
```

Comment: Are functions resolved as they are 'come across by the program' (for lack of a better way to put it). I am trying this now...

Comment: Wait, now I'm confused. I should wrap my for loop with another for loop?

Comment: I try, but I don't get it. What's the deal with the (i) showing up after the function is closed?

Comment: Did it work?  The (i) is passing the variable defined in the for loop into the function, that way the function defines it's own "i", which will not be affected by the outer for loop anymore.

Comment: No, Sir, not as I've tried it so far (in a couple of different places). But your explanation does make sense, except that I can't get it to work the way I would expect your explanation to apply, so not sure if I'm thinking of it right or not, really.

Comment: The `(i)` means the function is being invoked immediately after being defined

Comment: That's the self-executing part, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, then because functions take parameters _ByVal_, the `i` inside the function is henceforward immune to any changes of `i` outside the function (such as the loop incrementing).

Comment: Thank you very much for that, that helps me understand it a lot better. But I can't seem to wrap any part of the aforementioned code that doesn't produce a bunch of errors. I will have to take some time and research or find another way to accomplish what I am after (if there even is one).